# Why is regular expression matching so slow

Tags: regular-expression

I learned from [this article](http://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/) about `ripgrep` that regular expression engines that implement backtracking can be very slow in some cases, but I don't really understand why. Could someone explain in simple terms why the following python snippet, given as an example in the article linked, is very slow?

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search('(a*)*c', 'a' * 30)
```

Comment: This is easily Googled. Example hit: https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Comment: Yes, that article seems to cover it, thanks for the link!

Comment: It’s also discussed in detail in [Russ Cox’s articles on regular expressions](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an applied CS question unrelated to Unix & Linux as defined in the [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the issue is with the doubled repetition of the `a` in the pattern. The part `a*` allows for any number of `a`'s, while the surrounding `(·)*` *also* allows any number of the contained pattern.

This allows for a huge number of possible ways to match the pattern against a string of `a`'s. Ignoring the `b` for now, a string like `aaaaa` (five `a`'s) could be matched as `(aaaaa)`, `(aaaa)(a)`, `(aaa)(aa)`, `(aaa)(a)(a)`, `(aa)(aaa)`, `(aa)(aa)(a)` ... There's an exponential number of ways to match the string.

With the `b` at the end, a backtracking engine will try one way of matching the `a`'s, realizes it doesn't find the `b`, goes back one step, tries another way, realizes it can't find the `b`, ... and takes a long time to exhaust all possible arrangements, after which it fails.

---

There are much better texts on this subject online than I could ever write. Go read these:

- [Runaway Regular Expressions: Catastrophic Backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) by Jan Goyvaerts describes the issue and some ways to prevent it.
- [Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast 
  (but...)](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) by Russ Cox also describes the issue, as well as implementing regexes as finite automata, without using backtracking and therefore immune to this problem. It also has pictures.

---

In practice, if you can, avoid patterns that allow for multiple ways to match a string. The example here, `(a*)*c`, is obviously silly, since it's equivalent to `a*c` which doesn't have the nested repetition.